# Nvidia Quadro FX 380M drivers not working with Ubuntu 18.04LTS (HP-EliteBook-8440w)

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, hp

Nvidia Quadro FX 380M drivers not working with Ubuntu 18.04LTS (HP-EliteBook-8440w) , I am running the system now on Nouveau drivers but I feel I really need to install the Nvidia drivers to get the most our of it, besides I need the CUDA drivers for running ML on my laptop when on the move

Once I install the Nvidia proprietary drivers I get a black screen post login , I tried several DIY steps on youtube and stackexchange and still do not have a solution, Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to booting with parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`